# How to properly dispose ONNX model loaded with ML.NET

Tags: c#, ml.net

When I load an ONNX model and use it to make prediction with the following code everything works well

```
ITransformer pipeline = _mlContext.Model.Load(_model, out DataViewSchema predictionPipelineSchema);

using (PredictionEngine<TensorData, Prediction> predictionEngine = _mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<TensorData, Prediction>(pipeline))
{
   Prediction prediction = predictionEngine.Predict(tensorData);
   YH = (np.array(prediction.dense_3) * (maxOut - minOut) + minOut).ToArray<double>();
}
```

But if I load another model in the same AppDomain with the same statement

```
ITransformer pipeline = _mlContext.Model.Load(_model, out DataViewSchema predictionPipelineSchema);
```

I get the following exception:

[Exception in InferenceSession](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVARk.png)

It seems that the model is not properly released or disposed but I didn't find how to dispose the model.

Comment: I use ML.NET 1.4.0 and OnnxRuntime 0.5.1